# Django: Invalid block tag on line 14: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, html, django

During Django tutorial I've got an issue with index.html file.
I can't handle this exception:

> Invalid block tag on line 14: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

My index.html is like this:

```
    {% if latest_questions %)
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_questions %}
             <li> <a href="/polls/{{question.id}}"><b>{{question.question_text}}</b></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    Something else.
{% endif %}
```

I really don't understand why it don't recognize "else".

Comment: `% if latest_questions %)` is this a typo in the question or in the code? It should be `{% if latest_questions %}`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied without this. It's with {% at the begining.

Comment: but not at the end? in the end oyu have `%)` which should be `%}`, right?

Comment: your closing tag should be `%}`, and it will be ok

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Thank you!
I looked at this like thousand time and haven't seen that.

Comment: It's hilarious how the difference between a { and an ( can cost you 30 minutes of your life =p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your `if` tag.

Replace:

```
 {% if latest_questions %)
```

with:

```
 {% if latest_questions %}
```

Note the difference in the trailing character: `)` vs `}`

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen that. I focused on "else".

Comment: @Ula yep, actually the error only mentions the `else` tag so it can be confusing

Comment: I don't get it, the example has '{% if latest_questions %)' correctly, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Macilias the ending parenthesis is incorrect. It should be a curl bracket instead. ")" should be replaced by "}".

Comment: aha, the first one is missing so I was confused, and didn't get the other one was normal